# Add new post only in assigned category

Tags: posts, categories, users, user-roles

Is there any possibility or plugin, that alows me to add a user (example author role) who could add posts but only in one category?

Answer (score 0):

First [remove the category metabox](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) from the post edit screen for this particular role, let's name it `onecat-author`:

```
if (current_user_can('onecat-author')) {
  remove_meta_box ('category', 'post', 'normal');   
  }
```

Next, [when the post is saved](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) use the available hook to [assign the category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories):

```
if (current_user_can('onecat-author')) {
  add_action ('save_post', 'wpse_231846_save_cat', 10, 1 );
  }
function wpse_231846_save_cat ($post_id) {
  wp_set_post_categories ($post_id, array('the-id-of-that-category'));
  }
```

Note: the code is untested, so some debugging may be necessary.